# Getting confused by getting FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, filenotfoundexception

I've got that piece of code and just getting `FileNotFoundException`.

```
public class Overload {   
public void method(Object o) {     
    System.out.println("Object");   
    }   
public void method(java.io.FileNotFoundException f) {     
    System.out.println("FileNotFoundException");   
    }   
public void method(java.io.IOException i) {     
    System.out.println("IOException");   
    }   
public static void main(String args[]) {     
    Overload test = new Overload();     
    test.method(null);   
    } 
}
```

Any thoughts why does it happen?

Comment: what did you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it does access the most specific method, which in this case is `method(java.io.FileNotFoundException f)`

inheritence order from [FileNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html)

`java.lang.Object -> java.lang.Throwable -> java.lang.Exception -> java.io.IOException -> java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

As you can see, the `IOException` inherits from `Object` (at some point) which makes it more specific then `Object`. And the `FileNotFoundException` is more specific then `IOException`. In the end the compiler decides that it should call the method with the `FileNotFoundException` as parameter.

If there are two methods that are equally specific your code wouldn´t compile with the error that there is an ambiguous method call.

Answer (score 0):

**Most specific method argument is chosen for overloaded methods**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5

If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.